# How to update my web page using ajax with a single ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I am sending my ajax request to a servlet and my servlet gets data from the database
 and sending it back.

My question is database keeps updating 
and what I am doing for now is sending my ajax request over and over , 
that doesn't seems right cause everytime there will be a new `xmlhttprequest` object .

What can I do to avoid that and at the same time update my web page whenever something happens with the database is there any framework or something I should add to my project . This is my code to send ajax request:

```
        function startTimer(){
            setInterval("sendRequest()",1000);
        }



        function sendRequest(){

        var xmlhttp;
        var defaultLength;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest()){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else if(window.ActiveXObject()){
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }else{
            alert("not supported");
       }           

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            if(xmlhttp.status==200){
               var res = xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
               }



            }
        }

        }

        xmlhttp.open("post","ajaxservlet",true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);

        }`
```

Comment: There are probably a few different solutions - you've tagged this question with both `php` and `java-ee` - what technology are you running on the server?

Comment: sry its written in java

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). It's a framework for sending push notifications from server to client (it also depends on a JQuery plugin). Bit of a learning curve but it's a decent and widely used solution.

The code from a simple example is explained [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-The-Atmosphere-Framework-and-WebSocket).

There are also some example projects [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples).

Comment: thank you is there any other frameworks simmilar to atmosphere

Comment: You could also take a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) - bit easier to get your head around and also easier to integrate into existing projects. Hasn't had a release in a while but I think version 3 is pretty stable.